Keycode call,endcall
Try to send keycode to answer "call" and hang up "endcall" from arduino to android tablett.
I've been looking and haven't found a keycode that works.
This is what I have found!
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_CALL
Key code constant: Call key.
Constant Value: 5 (0x00000005)
Key code constant: End Call key.
Constant Value: 6 (0x00000006)
Have tried this mendet does not work
Key code constant: Call key.
Constant Value: 5 (0x00000005)
Key code constant: End Call key.
Constant Value: 6 (0x00000006)
